# Complex types used in a .NET DLL (but defined in an external Web Service) not available in VB6

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, com-interop

I developed a Web Service that checks user authorizations by querying a central database. It should be consumed by any application whenever a user starts it, in order to check if the user is allowed to run the application.
Since in the company there are many old applications written in Visual Basic 6 by people that do not have good programming skills, I'm trying to create a DLL that they can easily use in their VB6 applications to check user authorizations through a simple function call instead of dealing with details such as Web Service calls and XML messages.

I created a **Class Library** in Visual Studio 2010 using C#, which simply **wraps the Web Service functions**. I successfully created the DLL file and registered it (through RegAsm) into another machine used to develop Visual Basic 6 applications.

In VB6, the intellisense shows the functions exposed by the DLL (that can be called) but it is not working for the complex types returned by the functions.
For example, the DLL defines the following function, where the returned type (`User`) is defined into the Web Service code:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("AuthorLibrary.Author")]
[Guid("D2E23F5E-C209-464A-AF32-CC0251078076")]
//[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IAuthor))]
public class Author //: AuthorLibrary.IAuthor
{
    //[...]

    public User getUserData(string username)
    {
        ResponseMessageOfUser user;
        using (AccessControlSoapClient ws = new AccessControlSoapClient())
        {
            user = ws.getUserData(username);
        }
        if (user.response != ResponseType.Ok)
            throw new Exception(user.response.ToString());
        return user.result;
    }

    //[...]
}
```

In VB6, the following code runs correctly:

```
    Dim ws As AuthorLibrary.Author
    Set ws = New AuthorLibrary.Author

    Dim u As AuthorLibrary.User
    Set u = ws.getUserData("john.smith")
    Text1.Text = u.email
```

The problem is that when the developer writes `u.` nothing appears and so he does not know the available properties and/or methods for the object (even if, in the example above, `u.email` works).

Another method returns an instance of `Department` (let's call it `dept`). I can successfully print the values of simple `string` properties like `dept.Description` or `dept.Code`, but more complex properties such as `dept.childrenDepartments` - which should return a list of `Department` - give an error: "Missing object".

I think the problem is that **the DLL file does not show the classes/types/structures defined into the Web Service**. How can I do that?

I have also tried to define the following interface (`IAuthor`, as you can see from the first code), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("DB3BA840-B997-4D5E-86F0-0FC0A786C0D3")]
interface IAuthor
{
    //[...]
}
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but you're going to be fighting this at every step. The COM-callable wrapper *should in theory* be usable, but I wonder whether generate the classes from a VB6 soap tool would be more appropriate. Noting that the *most appropriate* approach here would be to encourage them to transition from VB6 - isn't that now dead, buried, salted, exhumed, re-checked, cremated and re-burried in a lead-lined coffin shot into space and heading slowly towards a distant star?

Comment: I agree with @MarcGravell: making this kind of interop work (even when VB6 was current and you were writing COM directly in C++) is an iterative process. There is no clear definition of the subset of COM that VB6 supports so you need to discover it. Eg. your problem might be in how the `User` type is defined (but we cannot see that). The best help I found was [*.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide*](http://my.safaribooksonline.coM/9780672333583) but it will still take some work. Suggestion: completely encapsulate the web service in an assembly (hide all the web service types).

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree with you. However, we have a lot of VB6 applications that we cannot quickly migrate to .NET. I tried to invoke the Web Service directly from VB6, but it is too hard and I cannot ask this effort to the "old" developers. I am also evaluating the possibility to develop a DLL directly in VB6, to make life easier to them...

Comment: @winterlude if you have a team of developers that are staunchly opposed to change, then you have a **real** problem, because this industry moves *fast*; this will ever-increasingly negatively impact not only technical issues (ability to consume data, technical support etc), but also on soft issues (ability to attract and retain staff, marketing, etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell you are right, but the core business of the company is not the development of software applications. There are few developers here and moreover some will retire in few months (so I cannot ask them to study .NET). Of course, we have to migrate all apps to .NET but not now, because we have more urgent things to do (like this one, i.e. managing the user authorizations through a central DB). :(

Comment: Hard to see why VB6 is relevant at all.  If the client used C# or Delphi or C++ then he'd have the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes, but the DLL is needed due to the lack of simple ways to consume a Web Service and handle its responses from code written in VB6. The other languages have wrappers or libraries that simplify the interaction (i.e. anyone can use them without taking care of XML, SOAP, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The [InterfaceType] attribute is indeed the key.  The default is `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch` if the attribute is not applied explicitly.  Which permits only *late-binding*, the equivalent of calling a method on an object reference of type *dynamic* in C#.  Note how you don't get IntelliSense for that either, the VB6 programmer has the same problem.

The IAuthor you tried probably doesn't work because you forgot to make it public.

So you need to get that attribute on the `User` class.  You'll have a problem because you didn't create that class.  So for one, you probably can't easily declare an IUser interface either.  The fallback for that is applying `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` on the class.  It isn't exactly the prettiest solution, that also exposes the members of System.Object and gives the VB6 programmer a dependency on the .NET Framework type library but that's not the end of the world.  You however still have to edit the class declaration to apply that attribute.

If it was generated from a web service then you'll have a maintenance headache.  Every time it is re-generated you'll have to make the edit again.  Then again, that is liable to break the VB6 code as well, it has to be recompiled.  So you might want to consider *isolating* that declaration so this isn't strictly necessary.  Declare your own User class and write the code to copy the fields/properties of the web service's User object to yours.  And of course you won't have any trouble writing an interface and applying the attribute.

Comment: I came to the same conclusions. The problem is that the `User` class is defined in the file `Reference.cs`, which was automatically added by VS when I added the reference to the Web Service. In that file, I tried to add `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` to both `User` and `Department` classes and it works.
Of course, it is not a good solution because I will loose any changes to that file every time I refresh the reference to the Web Service... but it works.
Creating an internal `User` class by copying every property of every returned object would introduce an additional overhead.

Comment: It is not the kind of overhead you ever worry about when you use a web service.  An extra dozen nanoseconds are completely invisible on operation that takes milliseconds.  Well, you know what to do, choosing between the alternatives is up to you.